# Transparent action bar not being fully transparent. (Leaves weirdbox)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, transparency, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I've tried setting the action bar I custom-made for my application to be transparent. However instead of being completely transparent, it leaves a weird elevation shadow:

http://puu.sh/rdYyb/04ce0147f6.jpg

**The XML for the bar:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/OverviewFAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_alert" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**The styles XML for my themes:**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"></style>
```

**How I programatically try to remove the elevation and background in the activity:**

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbarlayout);
    appBarLayout.setElevation(0);
    toolbar.setElevation(0);
    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
```

But despite all this the box (shown in the link) still persists... I'm not sure what's going on? Does anyone see anything wrong in my code?

Comment: try putting **app:elevation="0dp"**

Comment: nothing happened :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting inside app bar

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

this inside your toolbar

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Action bar completely disappears when I include app:elevation = "0dp"

Comment: Yeah but I have an icon which I want the user to be able to see. Currently the icon isnt visible but the functionality of the side navigation menu is still there

Comment: use   **app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"** inside your toolbar

**<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />**

Comment: change your code custom style parent to **ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark** . try to run and execute your project then it changes will reflects.

Comment: Yeah, I did this when I tried your suggestion and still couldn't see it

Comment: i wonder why it is not working for you. The same code works for me. I think there will be some issue with your style. Please accept this as an answer and upvote if it helps you upto some extent

Comment: Yeah changing the background of the app from the XML file which contained the toolbar/appbar fixed it. It now shows perfectly: http://puu.sh/reqsl/302741dcc1.jpg . Thanks

Comment: Glad it helps you @HHibari..  Please upvote the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I think you need to use "android:alpha="0.5" or use setAlpha() method.**

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and its worked for me and add this four line into toolbar widget in xml file.

```
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```