# How to create transparent actionbar with navigation drawer icon and option menu like this image screen

Tags: android

[image]

> how to create transparent actionbar like this image screen Please help me.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe what technology you are using to write your application (for example: Java, Xamarin).  Also describe what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have given the same answer already on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543177/transparent-action-bar-not-being-fully-transparent-leaves-weirdbox/39543207#39543207). Have a look into this if it helps. Let me know if need more help. Basically you need to give toolbar background as transparent.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Yes actionbar is transparent but is show different part from the my toolbar and activity content  I want same activity content and toolbar like screen shot

Comment: I think it is the exact same thing you want to implement. Just add the menu items in the toolbar and you will achieve  the same.

Comment: If you want to write something behind the toolbar, Place that view inside AppBarLayout but not inside the Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Set transparent background to the Toolbar.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

To setup Toolbar, refer this Android developer training:

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

Comment: Thanx but actionbar is different part from the my toolbar and activity content I want same activity content and toolbar like screen shot