# Navigation Drawer with Transparent Action Bar

Tags: java, android

I know this is a possible duplicate question but I need to create a transparent action bar with a navigation drawer to look like [image: this]. Here is my style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>   
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

and this is my drawer layout xml [xml code](https://pastebin.com/csTrScTK)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparent action bar not being fully transparent. (Leaves weirdbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543177/transparent-action-bar-not-being-fully-transparent-leaves-weirdbox)

Comment: @KanzariyaHitesh from my code what do I need to change?

Comment: @KanzariyaHitesh it doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

I would use toolbar instead of actionbar, its much easier to costumize and work with

Comment: I will provide you an example as soon as i reach my pc, if you alreayd havent found a solution

Comment: kindly provide still struggling since morning hours